# how to define calculated field in JSON schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

how do I define a computed field in json schema. say i have a schema with 2 integer fields. i want a third field which is a score field in the form, which adds up the values of the two other fields in the form. How can I define this in json schema?

Comment: Since I guess this field need to be dynamic as the 2 integer fields can change, I believe you want it to be a function rather then a field...

Comment: This is not possible with JSON Schema. Sorry.